# Two PNP Transistors - Jumper Collectors with Emitters and Bases at Same Potential?

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

In the attached image, OUT1 and OUT2 are logically identical (provided for redundancy).

[image]

I'm wondering if it's valid for OUT1 and OUT2 to be tied together and brought across a single load? This is necessary due to cable constraints.

My electronics knowledge is very rusty so any advice is greatly appreciated :^D

EDIT - Sorry for lack of info! The "load" is a 24V sinking input terminal of a programmable logic controller (PLC) whose purpose is to provide a ground path and read the received voltage as "high" (~24V) or "low" (~0V). I would imagine for theoretical purposes this could be looked at as a purely resistive load but to be honest I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? What is this load? Is it something small like a lamp, or a large load with power BJTs connected to the "main circuit"? Is it inductive? How are the bases driven? What is the overall purpose of your circuit? As it stands now, we see a few transistors connected to generic loads and are forced to guess at everything else.

Comment: Please go ahead and [edit] the clarifications directly into your post; comments are ephemeral and can disappear at any time, while the post body can contain code, equations, further images/schematics, and doesn't have a 600-character limit.

Comment: My primary concern is whether there are issues if the voltages OUT1 and OUT2 differ by some small amount due to slightly different drops across the transistors. For this reason, I'm wondering if connecting them in parallel may result in undesired operation.

Comment: How about a diode OR connection between the two?

Comment: @Aaron, this is probably the ticket - will either solder this on or custom-make a cable to avoid the issue altogether. Thanks!